# WEKA identical results performing Cross-Validation with KNN and different values for K

Tags: java, machine-learning, nlp, weka

I am using WEKA API to perform 10fold Cross-Validation on my dataset using a KNN (IBk) classifier. I have selected some values for K and have written some simple loops that performs CV for each such value of K.

When I look at the results, I notice that all results are identical even when I use a different K value. How is this possible? Just for clarification, I added the line of code where I specify the options that I feed to my classifier. This works perfectly when I'm doing normal classification (so no Cross-Validation).

```
"-K " + k_value + " -W 0 -I -A \"weka.core.neighboursearch.LinearNNSearch -A \\\"weka.core.EuclideanDistance -R first-last\\\"\""
```

As you can see I change the `k_value` in every iteration. Please some help!

**EDIT1**
Some additional code that maybe can help.

```
    Evaluation evaluation = new Evaluation(dataset);
    evaluation.crossValidateModel(knn, dataset, 10, new Random(1), new Object[] {});
    System.out.println("Error-rate " + evaluation.errorRate());
    writer.println("AUROC: " + evaluation.areaUnderROC(0));
    writer.println(evaluation.toClassDetailsString());
    writer.println(evaluation.toMatrixString());
    writer.println(evaluation.toSummaryString("\nResults\n======\n", true));
```

**EDIT2**
Instead of having `k_value` I replaced it with hard-coded values (here 10):

classification.setOptions("-K **10** -W 0 -I -A \"weka.core.neighboursearch.LinearNNSearch -A \\"weka.core.EuclideanDistance -R first-last\\"\"");

And again I get the exact same results as I had before when performing it with a different value of K. How can this happen? Is this how things work? Is this normal in weka?

Comment: Please can nobody help me out here? I have really looked into everything and nothing is 'wrong'. Everything works OK when I specify different values of K when NOT performing Cross-Validation. However in this scenario I always get the same results for each K. WHY?

Comment: Can you tell us something about the dataset? And what values did you try for k? (K is the number of neighbors and NOT the number of CV folds)